# EF Core 5.0 - Do you need to generate a migration when changing a "Defining Query" -mapped entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I added an entity class to my EF Core 5.0/MS SQL Server data model that is backed by a defining query (raw SQL query, with no table or view corresponding to it in my database).

When I make changes to it (for example, adding a new column) and then run `Add-Migration` in Package Manager Console to create a migration step, it generates a migration with empty `Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)` and `Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)` methods. But the generated [MigrationName].Designer.cs file contains the new column, and the ModelSnapshot for my DbContext gets modified to include the new columns, so *something* has changed.

My question is, do I need to add a migration each time I make a change to one of these entities in order for my app to function properly? If they're not needed, what is considered better practice when I update the defining query -backed entity:

A. Adding these migrations even though they have blank `Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)` and `Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)` methods, because the model changed, or

B. Not generating the migration and just having these changes get picked up the next time someone makes a change that actually impacts the underlying database structures?

Code snippets (over-simplified to remove identifying data):

Entity class

```
public class Thing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Configuration:

```
public class ThingTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Thing>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Thing> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasNoKey()
            .ToView("Dummy") // This is here to work around an issue with the migrations auto-generating a table for the entity - see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19972 
            .ToSqlQuery(
            @"SELECT
                [TableName].[IdColumn] AS Id,
                [TableName].[OtherColumn] AS Name
            FROM 
                [TableName]");
    }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
    {
    }

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Thing> Things { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(MyDbContext).Assembly);
    }
}
```

Examples of Migration partial classes that get generated:

Partial class with empty Up/Down methods:

```
public partial class MyMigration : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
    
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

Auto-generated __.Designer.cs file (the rest of the class):

```
[DbContext(typeof(MyDbContext))]
[Migration("20210302175116_MyMigration")]
partial class MyMigration
{
    protected override void BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
        modelBuilder
            .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128)
            .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "5.0.3")
            .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

        /* Entity configuration logic for all the other entities in my model.. */

        modelBuilder.Entity("MyDataProject.Thing", b =>
            {
                b.Property<string>("Id")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.Property<string>("Name")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.ToView("Dummy");

                b
                    .HasAnnotation("Relational:SqlQuery", "/* My SQL query */");
            });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
    }
}
```

Comment: `it generates a migration with empty Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder) and Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder) methods.` -- Are these methods located in partial classes?  I'm not an expert at migration in EF Core, but it sounds like it's creating these methods for you so that you can customize the migration process.

Comment: Yeah, they're in a partial class, and the rest of the class is autogenerated by the migration process (and has the desired changes). I'm not an expert at migration in EF Core either! I updated my question with an example of the partial classes.

Comment: OK, so that means your new field is located in the other partial class (the generated one), and you're done.  The empty methods you're referring to are placed into another partial class so that a regeneration doesn't wipe out any code you put there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If the database schema hasn't changed, you don't need to add a new migration.

Heck, you don't even *really* need to add a new migration if the new schema is compatible with the old one. For example, removing an optional property would still be compatible.

The *.Designer file is just there to occasionally provide additional information about the model when generating SQL. And, Since the migration doesn't generate SQL, it's entirely unused in this case.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude a query string used in `modelBuilder.Entity<MyQueryOnlyEntity>().HasNoKey().ToSqlQuery(someSqlQuery);` from the .Designer file then? It seems kind of wrong to me that is persistet in the model snapshot even though it is not used. Also, if using git, when would you include these changes to the snapshot? Create empty migrations to update the model - seems bad? Include in unrelated next migration commits - does not feel right either.